# ORM : Database Connection Managment in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm

I'm trying to build my own ORM (just for fun, not that I have to) in PHP, but I'm struggling a bit in managing database connection:

If I had some models like User, Post ... which are tables in the database, would it be okay to make a connection and close it every single time that I want something from the database or find a way to start up a single connection when the app boots and then just paste that connection whenever needed?

Comment: Opening a database connection is an expensive process. Maintaining a persistence connection across a request is idea.

Comment: Do you have a link or something where I can read or watch about maintaining a persistence connection ?

Comment: If you are building thus for fun, it will be more than worth it to see how established ORMs work out this and other problems. Check out Propel and Doctrine--both are established ORMs that have been around for nearly a decade.